# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating props.navigation.navigate)

Tags: react-native, icons, react-navigation

I have an icon on the right side of my Header. When pressed I want to be transferred to another page. However, it comes up with an error.
This is my 'icon' screen:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

  import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Login = props => {
return (
  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      <TouchableOpacity 
      onPress={() => {
        props.navigation.navigate({routeName: 'Login'});}}>
    <Image
      source={{
        uri:
          'https://clipartart.com/images/login-icon-clipart-5.jpg',
      }}
      style={{
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        borderRadius: 40 / 2,
        marginLeft: 15,

      }}  
    />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);
}


export default Login;
```

This is my 'navigation' screen:

```
  import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createAppContainer}  from 'react-navigation';
import React from 'react';

 import Homepage from './screens/Homepage';
 import Checkoutpage from './screens/Checkoutpage';
  import Filterpage from './screens/Filterpage';
 import Locationpage from './screens/Locationpage';
 import Menupage from './screens/MenuPage';
import Welcomepage from './screens/Welcomepage';
import Loginpage from './screens/Loginpage';
import Finalpage from './screens/Finalpage';
import Login from './Components/Login';


 const Navigation = createStackNavigator({
     Home:Homepage,
    Checkout: Checkoutpage,
Filter: Filterpage,
Location: Locationpage,
Menu: Menupage,
Welcome: Welcomepage,
Login: Loginpage,
Final: Finalpage
 },
 {
 defaultNavigationOptions: {
     headerRight:() => <Login/>
}
 }

);
```

I'm very new to react-native. So if you found the problem, can you please explain thoroughly so I understand. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

So it looks like you are expecting the `navigation` object to be part of the props passed to your `<Login/>` component. This object is [**only** defined for screen components](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop) in `react-navigate`.

This means that you need to get access to the navigation functionality some other way. Luckily, this library provides you with the [`useNavigation()` hook](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation). So using that in your component  would look something like:

```
// react-navigation v5+
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Login = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate({ routeName: "Login" });
        }}
      >
        <Image
          source={{
            uri: "https://clipartart.com/images/login-icon-clipart-5.jpg",
          }}
          style={{
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            borderRadius: 40 / 2,
            marginLeft: 15,
          }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: I did exactly as you told me to. It now comes up with a new error: (0, _native.useNavigation) is not a function. (In '(0, _native.useNavigation)()', '(0, _native.useNavigation)' is undefined). Do I need to download something?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are using React Navigation v4.x , in order to use the useNavigation hook you need to upgrade to v5.x.

The navigation prop will be passed to all screens by default and you can use the useNavigation hook like @faelks suggested (if needed in other components).

**UPGRADE TO v5 FIRST.**

Here you have a little example for v5.x version:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Button, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'

const Home = ({ navigation }) => (
    <View style={styles.component}>
        <Button title="Go to login" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')} />
    </View>
)

const Login = ({ navigation }) => (
    <View style={styles.component}>
        <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
    </View>
)

const Main = createStackNavigator()

const mainConfig = {
    // configuration for this stack
    initialRouteName: "Home",
}

export default props => (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Main.Navigator {...mainConfig}>
            <Main.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            <Main.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
            {/* Other screens for this stack */}
        </Main.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    component: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }
})
```

Comment: Is there another way to do this by using v4? I can't seem to download v5 @CevaComic